# If I'm an Apple iOS developer, can I do iOS upgrades, downgrades within the registered devices?

Tags: ipad, ios, upgrade, developer-program

I have an iPad 2 GSM with iOS 4.3.5 that I would like to upgrade to iOS 5.1.1.

I tried to upgrade using an Apple 5.1.1 image, without success due to the signing window for 5.1.1 being closed.

If I enroll in the Apple Developer program ($$$) will it be possible for me to upgrade to iOS 5.1.1? How about downgrade to other versions (e.g. 4.1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, being enrolled within the Apple Developer's Program does not provide you with any kind of *special* downgrade possibilities.

In the other hand, being a Developer grants you the ability to upgrade to the newest yet-to-be-released version of iOS.

So, being the iPad 2 [eligible](http://www.apple.com/ios/whats-new/) for iOS 6, you won't be able to *upgrade* it to iOS 5.1.1 instead, enrolled as a Developer or not.

Comment: As today if you need to test an application with ios 4.1 or 5.1 how you manage if you have a device with ios 6 ?

Comment: @PedroTiagoPereira There's no problem on testing an App deployed for previous iOS versions with a device with the latest version, it will work exactly the same. If the gap between version is too big, perhaps you'll find so deprecated code, though.

Comment: I understand that, but because you are using a new version you cannot be 100% sure, that a user with a previous iOS will have the same behavior. This is not the same, but the question is if a developer is an early adopter and upgrades the registered device, there is no way back for him ?

Comment: I'm afraid not. You could always use the Simulator or downgrade with the Jailbreak options.

Comment: uau, i'm surprised with the ios testing capabilities.

Comment: @PedroTiagoPereira: Most developers try to keep multiple devices around, with various versions of iOS. Marco Arment (of Instapaper and The Magazine) [talks about this in episode 69](http://5by5.tv/buildanalyze/69) of his podcast Build&Analyze. chpwn (creator of some iOS jailbreaks) has also [written a blogpost on this topic](http://blog.chpwn.com/post/19662817128). Unfortunately there is not much a single indie developer without many resources can do.